# Querying total row size in KBs for SQL Server DB based on date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, size, row

I've searched for this up and down, but I can't find how to query for a set of rows.

When I query the DB for the rows themselves, that's simple enough.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.[tablename]
WHERE CreatedDate < '2012-12-31-00:00:00'
```

But I'm not sure how to apply something like sp_spaceused to this.

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to get the "space used" by a rowset returned? Other than checking the datalength on each column (which will give you just the size of the rowset on the CLIENT) there is nothing that will give you the on-disk space used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to sum data size of each of the column like below

```
select SUM(datalength(col1))+SUM(datalength(col2))+.. from tableName
WHERE CreatedDate < '2012-12-31-00:00:00'
```

Here is a dynamic query that will fetch columns for the table and then add up the size for each column in a row and sum up the total size.

```
declare @table nvarchar(20)
declare @whereClause nvarchar(50)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

--initialize those two values
set @table = 'tableName'
set @whereClause = ' CreatedDate < ''2012-12-31-00:00:00'' '

set @sql = 'select ' + ' sum((0'

select @sql = @sql + ' + isnull(datalength(' + name + '), 1)' 
        from sys.columns where object_id = object_id(@table)
set @sql = @sql + ')) as totalSize from ' + @table + @whereClause 

select  @sql

exec (@sql)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Rajesh, the first query was good enough for my needs (I couldn't get the second to work), although I had to eliminate the 00:00:00 to get it to work.